# Groups theorem: Sylows theorem

Tags: group-theory

We are given a group $G$ and a surjective homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$ whose kernel has exactly $7$ elements.
Prove that $G$ has normal subgroups of order $7$,$14$,$21$,$28$ and $84$.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: This is not related to the Sylow theorems, but just an application of isomorphism theorems.

Comment: We know that ord(G) = 84 , we know that the 7-sylow group normal is  because there is just one 7-sylow group, we know that there must be  a 2-sylow group , and a 3-sylow group but we dont know how many

Comment: You do not need any of that for this. You know it has a normal subgroup of order $7$ because the exercise tells you this. You know you have the rest by the correspondence between subgroups of a quotient and subgroup of the group itself.

Comment: which isomorphism theorem do we have to use? the second or the third?

Comment: That depends on the ordering of them. You need to use the one that says something like what I said above.

Answer (score 2):

1. By the first isomorphism theorem
   $$
   G/\ker(\phi) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} =: G'
   $$
2. Now take any subgroup $H' < G'$, and consider $H = \phi^{-1}(H')$. Check that

a) $H \triangleleft G$

b) $\ker(\phi) \subset H$

1. Find $|H/\ker(\phi)|$ using another isomorphism theorem.

What are the possible values that $|H|$ can take?

Comment: We dont figure it out, maybe another hint/tip?

Comment: Which points are you stuck on? Tell me what you've done, and I will expand on my post after that.

Comment: @Phralad which isomorphism theorem do you have to use?

Comment: We first have find the subgroups H1 t/m H7 of G' and then we know that $Z_2xZ_6 $ abelian is so the subgroups are normal then we do | $\phi$-1 (H1) | = |H1| * |ker  $\phi$ | but why can we do this multiplication?

Comment: @Phralad We have found the possible values of |H| , but we dont know how to conclude that all of them must exist and not just one of them. How do we do that?

Comment: @heinz : Subgroups of all possible orders exist because, for each $n\mid 12$, there is a subgroup $H' < \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_6$ of order $n$

Answer (score 1):

Use the following two results:
1) If $\varphi:G\to H$ is surjective homomorphism, then $G/\ker(\varphi)\cong H$.
2) Let $N\lhd G$ be a normal subgroup. Then there exists a one-to-one correspondence between $\{K\lhd G/N\}$ and $\{M\lhd G|N\leq M\}$.